# Cannot position the barButtonItem in the lower corner of the navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

Currently having trouble changing the height of a barButtonItem. I've added a custom view and I'm also using a navBar that shows an enlarged title. I want the navBarButton item to be selectable even when the navBar with the large title is shown and update the position of the barButtonItem so that its adjacent to the title. The barButtonItem can't be placed in the lower corner of the navBar and the target for the barButtonItem won't register any clicks...

For some odd reason, I can only adjust the width of the customView but the height constraint conflicts with another constraint, possibly in the stackView.

I've changed the frame of the view and the location of the customView does change when the navBar is dragged, but it cant register any actions since the clickable area is constrained to a certain part of the navbar. Really perplexed

I've tried adding a custom view to the rightBarButtonItem, but ended up just changing the frame of the view to update depending on the size of the navBar.

```
func setupBarItem() {    
    guard let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar else {return}
    let image = UIImage(named: "large_shopping_cart")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)


    imageView.frame.origin.x = 0
    imageView.frame.origin.y = 0
    imageView.frame.size.height = 40
    imageView.frame.size.width = 40
    imageView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    imageView.backgroundColor = .yellow

    self.imageView = imageView

    self.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    self.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    let checkButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.imageView!)

    let otherButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "shopping_cart_icon"), landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tappedCheckout(_:)))

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedCheckout(_:)))
    print("This is the navbar height when the view loads \(navBar.bounds.height)")

    checkoutBarButtonItem = checkButton

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = checkoutBarButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    checkoutBarButtonItem?.customView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    navBar.layoutIfNeeded()

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar else {return}

//        print("\(navBar.bounds.height)")

    if navBar.bounds.height > 90 {

        imageView?.frame.origin.x = 0
        imageView?.frame.origin.y = navBar.bounds.height - 50

        imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large_shopping_cart")

        imageView?.frame.size.height = 40
        imageView?.frame.size.width = 40

    } else {
        imageView?.frame.origin.x = -10
        imageView?.frame.origin.y = 0

        imageView?.frame.size.height = 30
        imageView?.frame.size.width = 30

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `UINavigationBar` height isn't something that is normally altered, nor that with a `UIBarButtonItem`. If you think that isn't the issue and that some other element's constraint are the problem, try creating a blank project with *only* a navigation bar and see if you can achieve what you want. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I just changed the size of the UIBarButtonItem when the NavigationBar is enlarged. There's no other way around it, since the barbuttonitems are going in a stack view. Thanks though!